# Fantastico not automated enough

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

From a php script, I need to log into cPanel and run Fantastico De Luxe to install WordPress.  Anyone know how to do this?  Doesn't look like Fantastico comes with an API.

Comment: If you have Fantastico, what more needs automating? I don't get the point behind the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use php curl and emulate a browser calling it, call the cPanel url, parse the responses and then POST/GET the corresponding login data to it, then retrieve the Wordpress install page using the session info that must have been returned in the login call etc. (?) Though, as Matthew pointed out, it would be easier to just use Fantastico directly.

Or you could even have the Wordpress install code and run the install yourself instead of relying on Fantastico and adding layers in between.